# How to determine what id to use for columns that arn't using auto increments

Tags: python, database, sqlite, identity

I have created 4 tables and use ids to link them together. Now how do I determine what to use as ids?

tables creation

```
import sqlite3 as lite

queries = []

queries.append([''.join('CREATE TABLE Movie',
            '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,',
            'title INTEGER,',
            'genre INTEGER,',
            'cost INTEGER)')])

queries.append([''.join('CREATE TABLE Title',
            '(id INTEGER,',
            'English TEXT,',
            'Spansih TEXT,',
            'French TEXT)')])

queries.append([''.join('CREATE TABLE Genre',
            '(id INTEGER,',
            'Action INTEGER,',
            'Comedy INTEGER,',
            'Drama INTEGER',
            'Romance INTEGER)')])

queries.append([''.join('CREATE TABLE Cost',
            '(id INTEGER,',
            'Base INTEGER,',
            'Shipping INTEGER,',
            'Total INTEGER)')])
```

add row

```
title_id = None # How do i determines these?
genre_id = None # Should I just use Integer Primary Key for each table id? 
cost_id = None # But then how do I get those id values to put into 



queries.append('''INSERT INTO Movies 
            (title, genre, cost) VALUES(%d, %d, %d)''' %
            (titile_id, genre_id, cost_id))

queries.append('''INSERT INTO Title
            (id, English) VALUES(%d, %s)''' %
            (title_id, 'Movie 1'))

queries.append('''INSERT INTO Genre
            (id, Action, Comedy) VALUES(%d, %d. %d)''' %
            (genre_id, 1, 1,))

queries.append('''INSERT INTO Cost
            (id, Base, Shipping, Total) VALUES(%d, %d, %d, %d)''' %
            (cost_id, 50, 8, 58))


for q in queries:
    print q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
genre_id = None # Should I just use Integer Primary Key for each table id?
```

Each table's `id` should be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

```
title_id = None # How do i determines these?
cost_id = None # But then how do I get those id values to put into
```

Insert the title and cost before the movie. Omit manually setting the id (i.e. do `INSERT INTO Cost(Base, Shipping, Total) VALUES (..., ..., ...)` instead). Immediately after running an insert, use `cursor.lastrowid` to get the latest autogenerated id.